# Ubuntu 10.4 automatic wireless connection

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04

How to force Ubuntu 10.4 to automatically connect to my default wireless network on a system startup (without typing in password each time is connecting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.04 should connect to a wireless network on login. If you want to connect to wireless on boot, you will need to add ifconfig up commands in rc.local (or whatever the new init system Ubuntu uses.)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Yes, it does connect to a wireless network on login but ask me for my admin password every single time.

Comment: PS: my network manager: http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/

Comment: It might be asking you for the password to your default keyring. Changing your password will not change the keyring password, especially if you did it with the `passwd` utility as root (such as if you forgot it). See below answer.